# How can i compile the js file in asp.net mvc or asp.net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, globalization

Is it possible to compile the js file in asp.net or asp.net mvc like to support server side variables for example globalization or any other variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark View Engine supports this and actually works very well for this.

It allows you to use `~/` in your resource files URLs and translates it to the site root.

http://sparkviewengine.com/

Otherwise you could just write a Controller action that parses (and maybe compresses) those resource files for you.  This can be made easy by using something like [Packer](http://svn.offwhite.net/trac/SmallSharpTools.Packer/wiki).

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at [RazorJs](http://djsolid.net/blog/razorjs---write-razor-inside-your-javascript-files). It also has a [NuGet package](http://nuget.org/packages/RazorJS) available.